# Using buttons to trigger a Sub Procedure in Excel, this will split/copy data into a second sheet in the same workbook

Tags: vba, excel, subroutine

I currently have an Excel workbook which pulls data from a website that lists sign language interpreters from [here](https://www.illinois.gov/idhhc/licensure/Pages/Regions.aspx).

There are 7 different regions, or tables, I pull from.  The data is put into *Sheet1*, Columns *A*, *C*, *E*, *G*, *I*, *K*, *M* - all starting in row 1.  The VBA I have written then sorts/splits this data into Sheet2 using 8 buttons above the data - also located on Sheet2 using 8 buttons above the data - also located on Sheet2.

It allows me to sort between displaying all the data, or by region.  The code I use works really well but, it seems overly complicated and... well, not that good.  I feel like this isn't the most streamlined way, but it's what I currently know and can make function.  What I really want to know is, **Is there a better or simpler way?**  As one commenter told me, ,

> Don't write code that "works", write code your successor won't want to stab you for writing.
> -@Mat's-Mug

I agree.

Please help me with any gross errors regarding best practices, coding is not my profession, however, please correct me if you see something I should not be doing.  I am looking for guidance and picking things up as I go. Thanks!

#### TL;DR

I assign each button a macro which then calls a Sub that copies and splits the data from Sheet1 and displays it on Sheet2.

```
Public s1 As Worksheet
Public s2 As Worksheet
Public aRegions As Long
Public cCounty As Long
Public nEast As Long
Public nWest As Long
Public wCentral As Long
Public eCentral As Long
Public rSouth As Long
Public oState As Long
Public i As Long
Public K As Long
Public vConstants As Range
Public xConstants As Range
Public v As String

Sub AllRegions()

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

    K = 10

    vConstants.ClearContents

    CookCounty
    NortheastRegion
    NorthwestRegion
    WestCentralReg
    EastCentralReg
    SouthernRegion
    OtherState

    xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub

Sub ButtonOne()

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

    K = 10

    vConstants.ClearContents

    Call CookCounty

    xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub

Sub ButtonTwo()

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

    K = 10

    vConstants.ClearContents

    Call NortheastRegion

    xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub

Sub ButtonThree()

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

    K = 10

    vConstants.ClearContents

    Call NorthwestRegion

    xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub

Sub ButtonFour()

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

    K = 10

    vConstants.ClearContents

    Call WestCentralReg

    xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub

Sub ButtonFive()

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

    K = 10

    vConstants.ClearContents

    Call EastCentralReg

    xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub

Sub ButtonSix()

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

    K = 10

    vConstants.ClearContents

    Call SouthernRegion

    xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub

Sub ButtonSeven()

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

    K = 10

    vConstants.ClearContents

    Call OtherState

    xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub

Sub CookCounty()

    On Error Resume Next

    cCounty = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To cCounty
        v = s1.Cells(i, "A").Text
        If v = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            If v Like "Name:*" Then
                s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
                s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
            End If
            If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
            If v Like "License: General - *" Then
                    s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
                Else
                    If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            End If
            If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ", ")(1)
            If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 13) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub NortheastRegion()

    On Error Resume Next

    nEast = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To nEast
        v = s1.Cells(i, "C").Text
        If v = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            If v Like "Name:*" Then
                s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
                s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
            End If
            If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
            If v Like "License: General - *" Then
                    s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
                Else
                    If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            End If
            If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ", ")(1)
            If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 13) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub NorthwestRegion()

    On Error Resume Next

    nWest = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To nWest
        v = s1.Cells(i, "E").Text
        If v = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            If v Like "Name:*" Then
                s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
                s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
            End If
            If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
            If v Like "License: General - *" Then
                    s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
                Else
                    If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            End If
            If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ", ")(1)
            If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 13) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub WestCentralReg()

    On Error Resume Next

    wCentral = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To wCentral
        v = s1.Cells(i, "G").Text
        If v = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            If v Like "Name:*" Then
                s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
                s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
            End If
            If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
            If v Like "License: General - *" Then
                    s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
                Else
                    If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            End If
            If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ", ")(1)
            If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 13) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub EastCentralReg()

    On Error Resume Next

    eCentral = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To eCentral
        v = s1.Cells(i, "I").Text
        If v = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            If v Like "Name:*" Then
                s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
                s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
            End If
            If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
            If v Like "License: General - *" Then
                    s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
                Else
                    If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            End If
            If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ", ")(1)
            If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 13) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub SouthernRegion()

    On Error Resume Next

    rSouth = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To rSouth
        v = s1.Cells(i, "K").Text
        If v = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            If v Like "Name:*" Then
                s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
                s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
            End If
            If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
            If v Like "License: General - *" Then
                    s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
                Else
                    If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            End If
            If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ", ")(1)
            If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 13) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub

Sub OtherState()

    On Error Resume Next

    oState = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To oState
        v = s1.Cells(i, "M").Text
        If v = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            If v Like "Name:*" Then
                s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
                s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
            End If
            If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
            If v Like "License: General - *" Then
                    s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
                Else
                    If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            End If
            If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)
            If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ", ")(1)
            If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
            If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 13) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! You'll learn a ton - enjoy the ride!

Comment: I'm looking forward to it, thank you for the help earlier!

Comment: I would recommend writing a better Web Scraper.  Each informational entry is a row in a table  `<table class="soi-table table">` on the webpage.  This would be  fairly easy to parse.

Comment: Using your current data set and assuming that each entry is a set block of cells,it would be simpler to step through the entries 1 block at a time.   For example:  If each block is 10 rows and  `cells(1,1) = "Contact Information"` then`cells(11,1) = "Contact Information"`.   If this is the case then we can step through the code 10 rows at a time `For i = 1 to LastRow Step 10`

Comment: The answer I posted isn't correct because it doesn't output the records in the correct format.  However, this format is much easier to work with.  I suggest that you use my answer to compile the information and then write a routine to process the records.

Comment: Whenever possible you should include sample or mock data in your post.  You'll get much better responses by doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to modify build a Web Scraper to parse the records.

The other answers all bring up valid points.  I would add that you should replace all the **If Statements** with a **Select Case Statement** (see: `Sub AppendRecord` for an example).

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Const Regions_URL = "https://www.illinois.gov/idhhc/licensure/Pages/Regions.aspx"
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, div As HTMLDivElement, a As HTMLAnchorElement
    Set doc = getDocument(Regions_URL)

    ClearRecords

    Set div = doc.getElementById("wpzRight")
    For Each a In div.getElementsByTagName("A")
        ProcessRegion Replace(a.href, "about:", "https://www.illinois.gov")
    Next
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub ClearRecords()
   Worksheets("Records").UsedRange.Offset(1).ClearContents
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessRegion(URL As String)
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, tbl As HTMLTable, tr As HTMLTableRow
    Set doc = getDocument(URL)

    If Not doc Is Nothing Then
        For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByClassName("soi-table table")
            For Each tr In tbl.getElementsByTagName("TR")
                AppendRecord tr.innerText
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub AppendRecord(RecordText As String)
    Dim Name As String, License As String, License_Status As String, City_State As String, County As String, Cell_Phone As String, Email_Address As String, Region As String, Disciplined As String
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim arrLines As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    arrLines = Split(RecordText, vbCrLf)
    For x = 0 To UBound(arrLines)
        If InStr(arrLines(x), ":") Then
            Select Case Split(arrLines(x), ":")(0)
                Case "Name"
                    Name = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
                Case "License"
                    License = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
                Case "License Status"
                    License_Status = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
                Case "City/State"
                    City_State = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
                Case "County"
                    County = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
                Case "Cell Phone"
                    Cell_Phone = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
                Case "Email Address"
                    Email_Address = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
                Case "Region"
                    Region = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
                Case "Ever Been Disciplined?"
                    Disciplined = Split(arrLines(x), ":")(1)
            End Select
        End If
    Next

    With Worksheets("Records")
        Set Target = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Target.Resize(1, 9).Value = Array(Region, Name, License, License_Status, City_State, County, Cell_Phone, Email_Address, Disciplined)
    End With
End Sub

Public Function getDocument(URL As String) As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        If .readyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
            Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            Set getDocument = doc
        Else
            MsgBox "URL:  " & vbCrLf & "Ready state: " & .readyState & vbCrLf & "HTTP request status: " & .Status, vbInformation, "URL Not Responding"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Required References:

- Microsoft HTML Object Libary
- Microsoft XML. v#.#

[image: VBA References]

Comment: This works rather well for pulling the data, thank you.  I would like to ask, what is the benefit of using Select Case Statements in place of If Statements?

Comment: @C.Nug There is a insignificant performance benefit compared to the way that you used your if statements.  Ideally, you should have used `ElseIf` statements because `If v Like "License Status:*" Then` one occurs there is no reason to test `If v Like "City/State:*" Then`.   I recommended the `Select Case` statement  to improve readability.

Comment: I hope this is correct, would this change I made to the License Select Case Statement be correct?  The code works, but that doesn't mean it is correct:
`Case "License" If InStr(arrLines(x), ": General -") Then License = Split(arrLines(x), "- ")(1) Else License = Split(arrLines(x), ": ")(1) End If `
Again, this works to separate the License field from listing `"General - Master"` to just `"Master"` and the licenses which are not preceded by the word `"General"` will now also display correctly.  Also, how do I add a carriage return in these comments???

Comment: @C.Nug That is the way I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've already done this - `Tools>Options>Require Variable Declaration` - which makes sure you `Dim` your variables. If not do so, now, future-you will thank you.

---

You are using `s1` and `s2` and are only setting them to `Sheets("Sheet1")` and `Sheets("Sheet2")` respectively. This will break if you change the `Name` of the worksheet. You can get the same effect by using the worksheet `CodeName` property. You can see it in the `Project Explorer` window `View>Project Explorer` Ctrl+R for the shortcut. Likely you'll see `Sheet1 (Sheet1)`. The `CodeName` is on the left and the `Name` is what's displayed inside of `()`. Using `CodeName` will make your code less prone to breaking.

---

There is a lot of copy/pasting that was done. This makes it difficult to fix issues if you find there's a problem/bug with your code. You have to go back and make sure you get *every single spot* it was copied to. The better option is to follow DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). Where possible encapsulate your logic into a `Sub` or `Function` that does one thing, based on what you feed into it.

`CookCounty`, `NortheastRegion`, `NorthwestRegion` and all the rest are doing the same thing. The part that's different is the column that's being used for the row count. To make your code more generic replace `nEast` with `lastRow`.

> Old code: `nEast = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row`
>
> More Generic: `lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count,"C").End(xlUp).Row`.

There is still the `C` that's tying you to a specific column. You can remedy this by supplying an argument that represents column you want to use when you call the function. `PopulateGeographicArea(ByVal usedColumn as long)`

> Even more generic: `lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, usedColumn).End(xlUp).Row`

This takes what was 8 different methods and condenses them into 1 that you supply which column to use. Instead of `NortheastRegion` you'll have `PopulateGeographicArea(3)`.

---

This clears a lot of your public variables declared at the top. Do you want to remember that Cook County corresponds to Column 1, Northeast=3, Nothwest=5... Nope. Use an `Enum` (Enumeration) that will allow words to represent numbers. The `Enum` will start off at 0 if not specified and increment by 1 for each value that follows. `Unknown` is included to help prevent false positives from accepting a valid default.

```
Private Enum GeographicArea
    Unknown = 0
    Cook = 1
    Northeast = 3
    ...
End Enum
```

Previously you had to remember what the numbers were representing. Now change the method signature to be `PopulateGeographicArea(ByVal geoArea as GeographicArea)`. This makes your code self documenting, it should tell you what it is doing.

> Had to remember: PopulateGeographicArea(3)
>
> Immediately known: PopulateGeographicArea(Cook)

---

You have a lot of `If v Like "Name:*" Then` checks that are doing something. What is it doing? Incrementing a number or populating info. Create a `Sub` for each part and then supply to it the parameters it needs to do its job.

```
If v Like "Name:*" Then
    s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
    s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
End If
```

becomes

```
Private Sub PopulateName(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 1) = Split(Split(content, ", ")(1), " ")(0) 'FirstName
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 2) = Split(Split(content, ": ")(1), ",")(0) 'LastName
End Sub
```

Do the same to the entire block of `If v Like "Name:*" Then ...` checks and encapsulate them all into their own. This ends up with `Private Sub PopulateInformation(ByVal populateSheet As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)`.

---

Once done you end up with each piece self documenting what it's doing. Using good names for variables and methods (`Sub` and `Function`) that describe what they are doing help a lot.

```
Option Explicit

Private Enum GeographicArea
    Unknown = 0
    Cook = 1
    Northeast = 3 'without explicit numbering step of 1 for each entry
    Nothwest = 5
    WestCentral = 7
    EastCentral = 9
    Southern = 11
    OutOfState = 13
End Enum

Sub PopulateAllOfIllinois()
    
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, Cook
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, Northeast
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, Nothwest
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, WestCentral
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, EastCentral
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, Southern
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, OutOfState

    DeleteRangeAndShiftUp

End Sub

Sub ButtonOne()
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, Cook
    DeleteRangeAndShiftUp
End Sub

Sub ButtonTwo()
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, Northeast
    DeleteRangeAndShiftUp
End Sub

Sub ButtonThree()
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, Nothwest
    DeleteRangeAndShiftUp
End Sub

Sub ButtonFour()
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, WestCentral
    DeleteRangeAndShiftUp
End Sub

Sub ButtonFive()
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, EastCentral
    DeleteRangeAndShiftUp
End Sub

Sub ButtonSix()
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, Southern
    DeleteRangeAndShiftUp
End Sub

Sub ButtonSeven()
    PopulateGeographicArea Sheet1, Sheet2, OutOfState
    DeleteRangeAndShiftUp
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateGeographicArea(ByVal ws1 As Worksheet, ByVal ws2 As Worksheet, ByVal myRegion As GeographicArea, Optional ByRef K As Long = 10)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(10, "A"), ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "Z")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    On Error GoTo -1
    
    On Error GoTo DirtyExit
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, myRegion).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error GoTo -1
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Dim cellContent As String
        cellContent = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value2 'Value2 doesn't have rounding issues like Value. For numbers doesnt produce ### like Text can.
        
        If cellContent = "Contact Information" Then
            K = K + 1
        Else
            PopulateInformation ws2, cellContent, K
        End If
    Next

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub
    
DirtyExit:
    MsgBox "Please ensure columns are correct for your regions", vbOKOnly, "Incorrect region was used"
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateInformation(ByVal populateSheet As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    If content Like "Name:*" Then PopulateName populateSheet, content, checkRow
    
    PopulateLicense populateSheet, content, checkRow
    
    If content Like "License Status:*" Then PopulateLicenseStatus populateSheet, content, checkRow
    If content Like "City/State:*" Then PopulateCityAndState populateSheet, content, checkRow
    If content Like "County:*" Then PopulateCounty populateSheet, content, checkRow
    If content Like "*Phone:*" Then PopulatePhoneNumber populateSheet, content, checkRow
    If content Like "Email Address:*" Then PopulateEmailAddress populateSheet, content, checkRow
    If content Like "Region:*" Then PopulateRegion populateSheet, content, checkRow
    If content Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then PopulatePreviouslyDisciplined populateSheet, content, checkRow
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateName(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 1) = Split(Split(content, ", ")(1), " ")(0) 'FirstName
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 2) = Split(Split(content, ": ")(1), ",")(0) 'LastName
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateLicense(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    Dim license As String
    If content Like "License:*" Then
        license = Split(content, "- ")(1)
    End If
    
    If content Like "License: General - *" Then
        license = Split(content, "- ")(1)
    Else
        If content Like "License:*" Then
            license = Split(content, ": ")(1)
        End If
    End If
    
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 3) = license
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateLicenseStatus(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 4) = Split(content, ": ")(1)
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateCityAndState(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    Dim cityState As Variant
    cityState = Split(Split(content, ": ")(1), ",")
    
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 5) = cityState(0) 'City
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 6) = cityState(1) 'State
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateCounty(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 7) = Split(content, ": ")(1)
End Sub

Private Sub PopulatePhoneNumber(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    Dim columnOffset As Long
    If content Like "Home*" Then
        columnOffset = 0
    ElseIf content Like "Work*" Then
        columnOffset = 1
    ElseIf content Like "Cell*" Then
        columnOffset = 2
    End If
    
    Dim phoneNumber As String 'Assuming this is containing text
    phoneNumber = Split(content, ": ")(1)
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 8 + columnOffset) = phoneNumber
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateEmailAddress(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 11) = Split(content, ": ")(1)
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateRegion(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 12) = Split(content, ": ")(1)
End Sub

Private Sub PopulatePreviouslyDisciplined(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal content As String, ByVal checkRow As Long)
    ws.Cells(checkRow, 13) = Split(content, ": ")(1)
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRangeAndShiftUp()
    Sheet2.Range("H10:N10").Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

There are further optimizations that can be done but without running it I'm not exactly sure what they'll be. Any time you're about to copy/pasta ***stop***. Think about what's being done and ask yourself if you can create a method (`Sub` or `Function`) that you can supply arguments to.

Comment: Wow, what a great explanation and write up!  This has been extremely helpful.  Also, a big thanks to @Mat's-Mug.  
I am still very new to vba and coding in general, I will probably have a lot of questions about your code.  Please forgive delays between my responses.  I study and experiment your code one thing at a time and my understanding may not be as quick as others.

Answer (score 1):

So to begin with the biggest problem in your code is that you have written basically the same sub multiple times. However I see no problem using split if your data is consistent in terms of having the delimiter in each occurrence.

Also setting the vConstants and xConstants, which I'm a bit confused by without seeing the *Sheet1*, multiple times for each button is unnecessary. Something along the lines of:

```
Public selectedCol as Integer
Sub ButtonOne()

selectedCol = 1 ' Change this according to the button.
Call GetRegion(selectedCol)

End Sub
```

And for the main method itself:

```
Sub GetRegion(iCol as Integer)

Dim nRegion as long
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set vConstants = s2.Range("A10:Z99999").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
Set xConstants = s2.Range("H10:N10")

K = 10

vConstants.ClearContents

On Error Resume Next

nRegion= s1.Cells(Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To nRegion
    v = s1.Cells(i, iCol).Text
    If v = "Contact Information" Then
        K = K + 1
    Else
        If v Like "Name:*" Then
            s2.Cells(K, 1) = Split(Split(v, ", ")(1), " ")(0)    'First Name
            s2.Cells(K, 2) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)    'Last Name
        End If
        If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
        If v Like "License: General - *" Then
                s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, "- ")(1)
            Else
                If v Like "License:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 3) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        End If
        If v Like "License Status:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 4) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 5) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ",")(0)
        If v Like "City/State:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 6) = Split(Split(v, ": ")(1), ", ")(1)
        If v Like "County:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 7) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        If v Like "Home Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 8) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        If v Like "Work Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 9) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        If v Like "Cell Phone:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 10) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        If v Like "Email Address:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 11) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        If v Like "Region:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 12) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
        If v Like "Ever Been Disciplined?:*" Then s2.Cells(K, 13) = Split(v, ": ")(1)
    End If
Next i

xConstants.Delete xlUp

End Sub
```

Also I would consider using a combobox to select the region instead of multiple command buttons. You probably have the column headers in the *Sheet2*, but I would also consider populating them into an array and adding them in the beginning of the main sub.

Hopefully this helps. If you post the workbook I can look into it a bit better as I can't say much about the main sub itself without the data.

Comment: Let's ignore the lack of using With statement and  the amount of the If clauses first.